# if(!is_user_logged_in()) returns true when 404

Tags: debug

I'm running a closed website for registered users only.

For doing so I check in if user is logged in

```
// no non-authenticated users allowed
if( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
    wp_redirect('/wp-login.php');
    //auth_redirect();
    exit;
}
```

But sometimes It just logged me out, and I could not understand where to seek the problem. it happened ocassionally and so it was really hard to debug.

Now: with different function I found that `if( !is_user_logged_in() )` returns true on 404 page.

I'm still debugging but I want to hear your opinion, is this normal or intended? Could you confirm if this is same with your installaton? I'm running latest version of Wordpress

---

Update:

still cant undestand, in footer.php

```
if(!is_user_logged_in()) {
    echo '123';
}
```

echos 123
but my function does not redirect.. but its still strange and have problem with another plugin because of this.

plugin looks like this:

```
add_action("wp_footer","bpln_store_ids");
function bpln_store_ids(){
    if(!is_user_logged_in())
        return;
 ?>
 <div id="bpln-notification-ids" style="display:none;">
 <?php echo join(",",bpln_get_all_notification_ids(bp_loggedin_user_id()));?>
 </div>
<?php
}
```

since check returns true, the actual content will never be displayed

Comment: Where are you doing your check? You can only do a redirect before any HTML is outputted. If you call for a redirect after the content has started being sent, it will be ignored.

Comment: I use this in header, before the doctype. but problem rises in footer.php. I updated my question. This is still a problem. can you confirm if this is same everywhere? I also think this is a bug

Comment: I'm not having any issues with `is_user_logged_in()` reporting the wrong thing on the `404` page - even in the footer. You may have a plugin that is changing the state of the current user. You need to disable plugins  and non-default themes to determine if it is one of those first. If the issue exists with a stock WordPress install, then it is a WordPress issue, otherwise it is has to do with an add-on.

Comment: Is there a link we can visit to see it in action?

Comment: You shouldn't use redirect in the `header.php` file, that's usually too late, the headers are then already sent. So hook it earlier, for example the `template_redirect` hook.

Comment: @birgire As a separate answer, please.

Comment: @kaiser, thanks for the reminder -  I know, it's a bad habit hinting for the answer in the comments ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Please try this for your redirect:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function(){

    // no non-authenticated users allowed
    if( ! is_user_logged_in() )
    {
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/wp-login.php' ), 302 );
        exit();
    }
});
```

to allow only logged in users to view your site.

It's generally too late to use redirect directly in the `header.php` file, so it's better to use an hook that fires before *http headers* are sent, like the `template_redirect` hook. It's also important that `template_redirect` is not activated on the `wp-login.php` page.

Comment: Here go the upvotes. How easy was that? ;)

Comment: I wont mark this as a correct answer, since question is different, but this is interesting and might be my other problem, ill try this

Comment: Okay, tried this but does not work, when I'm logged out, I still can view the site. maybe template_redirect is a wrong action?

Comment: That's strange, I've tested it with success on a vanilla install. Maybe you are using a plugin/theme that's interfering? Maybe you got some cookie problems, did you try this in another browser or clear cache?  You can try another earlier hook like `wp`, but if you want to use hooks like `init` you have to change the above code to avoid *infinite loop*.  What's the output of `home_url( '/wp-login.php' )`? What happens if you replace `wp_redirect()` with `die( 'Stop!' )`? Did you add the code snippet into your `functions.php` file?